# Angular 2 - Return true or false for elements in ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to show events based on user id or `this.uid` in my case, but I'm not sure how to get it working.

view

```
<md-card *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a *ngIf="checkGuest(event.$key) === true" [routerLink]="['event', event.$key]">
        <img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" />{{ event.name }}</a>
</md-card>
```

component

```
  checkGuest(eventKey: string): void {

    this.db.object(`/events/${eventKey}/guests/${this.uid}/`)
      .subscribe(user => this.hello(user));
  }

  hello(user): Boolean {
    console.log(user);

    if (user) {
      console.log('hello');
      this.isUser = true;
    }

    return false;

  }
```

Comment: What do you get on console?

Comment: I get the user object from the database and "hello"

Comment: so you want to show `{{event.name}}` if `checkGuest()` method is true?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need.

Comment: This code will never work. Absolutely wrong.

Comment: I figured that ... how can I get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your checkGuest to return an `Observable`, then use the `async` pipe again.

```
checkGuest(eventKey: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // a return here
    return this.db.object(`/events/${eventKey}/guests/${this.uid}/`)
        .map((user) => this.hello(user));
  }

  hello(user): Boolean {
    console.log(user);

    if (user) {
      console.log('hello');
      this.isUser = true;
      // you need a return here
      return true;
    }

    return false;

  }

<md-card *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a *ngIf="checkGuest(event.$key) | async" [routerLink]="['event', event.$key]">
        <img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" />{{ event.name }}</a>
</md-card>
```

Comment: @Ciprian See my edit. Also, "it does not work" is not very helpful when you need an answer.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. It never reached the hello method. No hello logged or anything.

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Only think I noticed is that it should be `Observable<Boolean>`

Comment: @Ciprian I corrected it. You should take note of various observable operators.

Comment: I will. Thank you again